# How to use ES (Edge selection) in R and how to interpret results obtained from that

Tags: r

I am using `ES()` function in R on marks data set which is an inbuilt data set in R.
Here is sample code showing what I've done so far but I don't seem to be able to interpret the results I got:

```
library("ES") 
library("RColorBrewer") 
data(marks) 
require(graphics) 
attach(marks) 
object<-ES(marks)
```

How does `ES()` work and how do I interpret the results obtained?

Comment: Do you mean the `es` function? Please include sample code showing what you have tried,current output and what exactly has failed to work or what exactly you need clarification on. Include what package(s) you're using.

Comment: @NelsonGon this is the sample code: install.packages("ES")
library.packages("RColorBrewer")
library("datasets")
library("ES")
library("RColorBrewer")
data(marks)
require(graphics)

attach(marks)

object<-ES(marks)

when you type object you get the results. i don't seem to be able to interpret the results i got.

Comment: @newguy I am talking about Edge selection not exponential smoothing.

Comment: The [ES manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ES/index.html) doesn't give much help, and the references are incomplete. Perhaps (what I am assuming is) the [relevant paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949655.2018.1511714?journalCode=gscs20) will help.

Comment: @user20650 thanks, i read that paper before and researching about every technical definition helped me a little to understand few results.